# I get this error when trying to run a test using Selenium: Launch configuration AWTConsole references non-existing project testProject

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, testing, selenium

'Launch AWTConsole' has encountered a problem.
Launch configuration AWTConsole references non-existing project testProject.

has anyone had this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not related to your selenium code. You need to right click on your source file and:

> "Run As -> Java Application"